# Android - How to get context from a non-activity, non-fragment static class?

Tags: java, android

I'm writing a class that contains functions of frequent use. Something like this:

```
public class myLib{

public static String var1="...";
public static Int var2 = 123;
public static void function1() {...}
public static void function2() {...}

}
```

This lib is intended to be used in android projects, and some of those static functions require access to the application context. How do I get the application context of the application calling these static function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the context from function parameter and pass the context whenever you call the function from fragment or activity.

```
public class myLib{

public static String var1="...";
public static Int var2 = 123;
public static void function1(Context context, ...) {...}
public static void function2() {...}

}
```

from Activity,

```
myLib.function1(this,...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass Context as a param to methods that need it.

The param can be `final @NonNull Context context`

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling static function from Activity then during calling just pass context as parameter.

Otherwise extend your class as Application and create constructor and use context.